# Check if element is visible for certain percentage on screen (viewport)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i detect if some element is visible? For better understading look at the image below.

[image: Screen with half-visible image]

I want to fire event when the image is half-visible. It would be great if it would work for all browsers and devices (tablets and smartphones).

Comment: Is your image absolutely positioned? Also, awesome avatar!

Comment: Yes, image is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Jquery.fracs](http://larsjung.de/fracs/) plugin seems to do exactly what you need.

```
function callback(fracs: Fractions, previousFracs: Fractions) {
    if(fracs > 0.5)
      doSomething();
};

var fracs = $("img").fracs(callback);
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code for triggering an event. It may be slow-ish though.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on mobile when the user zooms in and out

Answer (score 3):

Your Window is between

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

and

```
$(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()
```

If the

```
$(element).offset().top
```

falls between those, it should be visible.

EDIT: I am assuming your element (whose visibility is to be determined) is absolutely positioned. If not, it would be a bit more complicated.

EDIT2: This is only to determine visibility in case of vertical offset. For the horizontal version, replace "scrollTop" with "scrollLeft", "height" with "width" and "top" with "left".

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat plugin, [jQuery fracs](http://larsjung.de/fracs/) written specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check whether the item is viewable from the bottom of the screen or the top. so the logic would be this:

```
on window scroll event
if item.y is less than scroll.y, calculate amount off screen
if item.y + item.height is greater than scroll.y + scroll.height, calculate amount off screen
deduct both values off the item.height to find the total off screen
create a percentage of this
```

So in javascript this would work something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('item1'),
    rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    item = {
        el: el,
        x: rect.left,
        y: rect.top,
        w: el.offsetWidth,
        h: el.offsetHeight
     };

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    var deduct = 0,
        percentage = 0,
        x = window.pageXOffset,
        y = window.pageYOffset,
        w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;
    if (item.y < y) {
        deduct += (y - item.y);
    }
    if ((item.y + item.h) > (y + h)) {
        deduct += (item.y + item.h) - (y + h);
    }
    if (deduct > item.h) {
        deduct = item.h;
    }
    percentage = Math.round(((item.h - deduct) / item.h) * 100);
});
```

I've excluded the support for older browsers, but if you need it it would be:

```
x = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft,
y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop,
w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $w = $(window), wh = $w.height(),
    top = $w.scrollTop(), bottom = top + wh,
    $img = $("#image"),
    imgCenter = $img.offset().top + $img.height()/2;
if (imgCenter >= top && imgCenter < bottom) {
    // the image is half-visible
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of the answer would be helpful here